# Weird lines in the print at specific heights

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, extruder, underextrusion

I recently upgraded my Ender 3 printer with all metal extruder and upgraded my mainboard from 4.2.2 to 4.2.7 silent board. I also added a Creality touch sensor for auto bed leveling.

Before these upgrades the prints were coming out fine. But after all these upgrades I printed the xyz calibration cube and it came out with weird lines in the print like in the below images.

[image][image][image][image][image]

It looks like there are 2 issues. One at the top where it looks like it has under extruded and the other at the bottom where it has some weird line. Also these line appears at the same exact height and I tried printing the same cube multiple times and the result is the same. I need help in figuring out what this issue is, why it is occurring and how do I fix it.

Comment: might there be a bad spot on the leadscrew?

Comment: @Trish I checked it. It looks good to me. There is no bending or deformation of the screw. Not sure what might be the issue.

Comment: Do the lines occur at the same height as inner floor and roof of the cube?

Comment: @Gauthier Yes for that xyz cube it occurs at the same height always.